# Combination of data.table and str_extract_all

Tags: r, regex, data.table, stringr

I want to have one column for every number in a `data.table` per grouping variable.
Suppose I have the following data:

```
Data <- data.table(Text = c("123 456", "234 567"), Group = c("A", "B"))
      Text Group
1: 123 456     A
2: 234 567     B
```

What I want:

```
      Text Group Number1 Number2
1: 123 456     A     123     456
2: 234 567     B     234     567
```

What I've tried:

```
Data[, c("Number1", "Number2") := str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+"), Group]
```

This gives me the following:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(Data, , `:=`(c("Number1", "Number2"), str_extract_all(Text,  : 
  Supplied 2 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 1 in column 'Number1'. The RHS length must either be 1 (single values are ok) or match the LHS length exactly. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() explicitly to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

I know I can use `separate`, I know I can use one regular expression per number/column, but I want a smart solution in "one line" with `str_extract_all`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this by `Group`, you can use `Data[,paste0("number", 1:2) := stringr::str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+")]` Or simpler `splitstackshape::cSplit(Data, "Text", sep = " ", drop = FALSE)`

Comment: Because in my real data the information is in only one line in each group. But you're right, the first solution works and after that I can fill the missing values for each group. Thank you!
Edit: No, does not work for my example.

Comment: I think it does not, it gives columns in different order but `cSplit` solution works though.

Comment: What worked for me the best: `Data[,paste0("number", 1:2) := transpose(str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+"))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have used `cSplit` as it is

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(Data, "Text", sep = " ", drop = FALSE)
```

However, if you want to use `str_extract_all` we can do

```
Data[,paste0("number", 1:2) := purrr::transpose(stringr::str_extract_all(Text, "\\d+"))]
Data

#      Text Group number1 number2
#1: 123 456     A     123     456
#2: 234 567     B     234     567
```

Comment: Thank you! `transpose` was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `fread`

```
Data[,  c("Number1", "Number2") := fread(text = Text)][]
```

Answer (score 1):

A "one-line" solution using trstrsplit:

```
Data[, c("Number1", "Number2") := tstrsplit(Text, " "), Group]
      Text Group Number1 Number2
1: 123 456     A     123     456
2: 234 567     B     234     567
```